# Compute gradient of discretized energy function

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, optimization, regularization, discrete-calculus

Given the following discretized energy problem, I'd like to compute the gradient with respect to $u[i]$:

$$
\min _{u} \sum_{i=1}^{N-1}|u[i+1]-u[i]|+\frac{\lambda}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{N}(u[i]-f[i])^{2}
$$

I have the following solution but I can't come up with it myself.

$$\nabla E[i]=\operatorname{sign}(u[i]-u[i-1])-\operatorname{sign}(u[i+1]-u[i])+\lambda(u[i]-f[i]) \quad \forall 1<i \leq N-1$$

I understand that the derivative of the $|x|$ function is $sign(x)$ but I don't see why there are two $sign$ terms. Basically, my calculation is:

$$\frac{d}{d\;u[i]}|u[i+1]-u[i]| 
\\= \operatorname{sign}(u[i+1]-u[i])*\frac{d}{d u[i]}(u[i+1] - u[i])
\\= \operatorname{sign}(u[i]-u[i-1])*\frac{d}{d u[i-1]}(u[i] - u[i-1])
\\
= \operatorname{sign}(u[i]-u[i-1])*(\frac{d}{d\;u[i-1]}u[i] - 1)$$

This is where I get stuck and can't come up with the provided solution. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the meaning of "min u" there.  But if I can lay that aside, look at some $u$ in particular, $u[3]$, say.  It shows up not *once* in the calculation, but *twice*, in two terms $|u[3]-u[2]|$ *and* $|u[4]-u[3]|$.  You have to account for both of them.  If you understand where the "sign"s come from, you can take it from there.

Comment: Ok, so this means $\frac{d}{d\;u[i-1]}u[i] = 0$, right?

Comment: @dragontrainer  Yes.  Because $u[i]$ is never the same variable as $u[i-1]$.